# File metadata is saved in file body in WCF file upload by Stream

Tags: c#, wcf, filestreams

I am uploading a file through a WCF service.

```
 [OperationContract(Name = "UploadManual")]
        [DataContractFormat]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   UriTemplate = "UploadManual/",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string UploadManual(Stream Uploading);
```

Implementation

```
public string UploadManual(Stream Uploading)
        {
            using (FileStream writer = File.Create(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ProductManual/Temp.txt")))
            {
               Uploading.CopyTo(writer);

            }    
            return "Response"
        }
```

But the file is saved along with meta data as below.

**---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="FileName.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
File Content
---------------------------acebdf13572468--**

But i want only content to be saved in the file.
How to resolve the issue?

Comment: What does the client sending?

Comment: a text file.i am testing it through fiddler.

Comment: It seems OK, folowing link does the same, are you sure the client does not send the Meata as a part of the content? [File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757991/File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript)

Comment: yes i am sure. the metadata is not part of file content.